# Using R.Net running an R-script using RODBC: "first argument is not an open RODBC channel"

Tags: rodbc, r.net

Running this script from within R works fine.

```
library(RODBC)
con<- RODBC::odbcConnect("NewEHMP", uid = "", pwd = "")
arr<-RODBC::sqlFetch(con, "AllEHMPSites", max = 10)
odbcCloseAll()
```

Running the same script from VS20129 VB.Net using R.Net:

```
m_REngine.Evaluate("source('" + scriptpath + "')")
```

traps the following error: '*RDotNet.EvaluationException: 'Error in RODBC::sqlFetch(con, "AllEHMPSites", max = 10) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel*'

Note that other scripts run via R.Net  work fine as long as it does not use an RODBC connection.
Any suggestions would be very welcome.
Cheers

Tried different connection strings and different RODBC sql  approached (sqlQuery, sqlFetch).
As the script runs fine from within R but false using R.Net, it seems a R.Net problem to me.

Comment: One step in the right direction was to compile the code for X86 CPU only.